# Outlook VBA Script auto save attachment using information in body of email to name the file

Tags: outlook, rename, attachment, autosave

Need a VBA script to autosave attachments but need to use information in the body of email to name the saved file.  Example of email:

Delivery Information:

Message #:      246439839

Local Number:       2395945852
Remote CSID:        2399318665
Remote CID:     2392780330
Total Pages:        1

Receive Time:       6/8/2016 7:09:50 AM PDT
Transmit Time:      32.000 sec

filename would be:
NM-246439839-LN-2395945852-CSID-2399318665-CID-2392780330.pdf

Files are always PDF format

Local Number, Remote CSID and Remote CID are not always populated (which is why I need all of them to be able to use whichever one is populated for filtering).

Message # needs to be part of filename to ensure a unique name for each file.

The email is HTML format and is always the same so might be able to use the tags, I can post the HTML if needed.

I already have created scripts that monitor the folder and then sorts/moves the files to the appropriate places based upon file name.  The emails are coming from our new fax provider and they are unable to add these to the subject line like our previous system.

Currently using:

```
Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
Dim saveFolder As String
    saveFolder = "c:\Data\Fax"
    For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
        objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & objAtt.DisplayName
        Set objAtt = Nothing
    Next
End Sub
```

Thank you for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Just reference sample code, you could update it as your needs:

```
Public p As String 'File Save location, also unzip the file storage location
Public Sub SaveAttach(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
    p = "C:\Users\Administrator.TXV6HLXTU3ZW8KD\Desktop\"
    SaveAttachment Item, p, "*.rar"  'Here *.rar can be changed to other regular expressions
    ' MsgBox "File saved."
End Sub

' save file
' path is the save path, condition is the attachment name match condition
Private Sub SaveAttachment(ByVal Item As Object, path$, Optional condition$ = "*")
    Dim olAtt As Attachment
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim m As Long
    Dim s As String
    If Item.Attachments.Count > 0 Then
        For i = 1 To Item.Attachments.Count
            Set olAtt = Item.Attachments(i)
            If olAtt.FileName Like condition Then
                olAtt.SaveAsFile path & olAtt.FileName
        'The following section is to extract the rar file, p is the save location
                s = "C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" & " X " & path & olAtt.FileName & " " & p 'Note Find the Decompression software location
                m = Shell(s, vbHide)
            End If
        Next
    End If
    Set olAtt = Nothing
End Sub
```

Then in Outlook to create a new rule, select the action for the execution of the script, select the script for this method, you can receive the message automatically save attachments and extract to the desktop.

Comment: I need to name the file (a pdf file) with the numbers listed in the body of the email.  The numbers after CSID: and CID: